# How does cassandra handle reads before data has been replicated?

Tags: cassandra

Lets say I write some data to SERVER-A, then try to read it from SERVER-B before the data has been replicated. Which version of the data do I see?

I think I shouldn't see SERVER-A's write. But is this where consistent hashing comes in? That read request should be routed to SERVER-A?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on

1. if you're using the **same client** to read & write
2. if the client is waiting for a successful write to start reading
3. the **consistency level** used for write & read

If you write at **QUORUM** and wait for successful ack before reading at **QUORUM** then you will be able to see your own write (or newer written value)

If you write at **ONE** and wait for successful ack before reading at **ONE** then you **may** see old value and not your own write

If you don't wait for successful write before start reading, there is no guarantee to see your own write, although it might be possible (because the write is very fast in some case)

Read this: http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/cassandra-introduction-2016-60292046/31